# Getting frame width of UIPickerView

Tags: uipickerview

How do I get the frame width dimensions of a UIPickerView? I need to calc the total view width - the frame width on both the left and right sides of the UIPickerView. In other words, view.frame.size.width or view.bounds.size.width minus the widths of both the left and right sides of the picker.

Comment: How do we close old outdated questions?